# In Japanese, how do you say you will skip ahead past one section for time's sake while reading aloud to an audience?

Tags: set-phrases, politeness, phrase-requests, jargon, academic-japanese

How do you succinctly say that you are going to skip ahead past the next section or paragraph for time's sake and tell the audience which spot you are picking up again when reading a paper aloud at an academic conference?

I believe that there is a Japanese phrase that's a sort of set phrase (though different people might word it slightly differently) of about 1 sentence long, which includes the word 「飛ぶ」or「飛んで行きます」 ("fly past" or "jump over" the next bit) and tells the listeners the first couple words of the sentence where you will start up reading aloud again. I think the phrase translates to something like, "I'm going to 'fly past' the next section and resume reading at [the 2nd paragraph of page 3, starting from, 'さらに、']." I heard it used 2 years ago so my memory of how this was expressed is fuzzy.

If there is not a standard phrase for this, how can I say it very succinctly (and quickly)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「[割愛]{かつあい}」 is a formal word so appropriate to use in a formal situation as suggested by eltonjohnさん.

「[飛]{と}ばす」and 「[省略]{しょうりゃく}する」 have similar meanings, but 「割愛する」 is more appropriate in this case, because 「割愛」 is formal and has a special nuance for it. While 「飛ばす」 and 「省略する」 simply mean "omit", 「割愛する」 means "I do not want to omit [this/it/etc] but now I need to due to the inevitable reason, so I omit [this/it/etc] for this time".

Here are some examples of sentences using 「割愛する」 in a colloquial context in a formal situation.

> 「[時間]{じかん}の[関係]{かんけい}[上]{じょう}（／[都合]{つごう}[上]{じょう}）、[内容]{ないよう}の[一部]{いちぶ}を[割愛]{かつあい}させていただく[場合]{ばあい}がございますが、ご[了承]{りょうしょう}いただければと[思]{おも}います」（If the speaker says this at the beginning, s/he does not have to mention the time matter after that.）

> 「[続]{つづ}きまして（イ）がございますが、[本日]{ほんじつ}は時間の関係上、[割愛]{かつあい}させていただきます。[次]{つぎ}の２ページに[参]{まい}りまして（ウ）からとなりますが、……」（If the speaker mentions the time matter at the point s/he does the first 割愛, s/he does not have to mention the time matter after that.）

> 「続きまして、３ページ[目]{め}に[移]{うつ}りまして（エ）がございますが、こちらは割愛させていただきまして、（オ）に参ります」

> 「[次]{つぎ}の（カ）は割愛させていただきまして、５ページ目の（キ）に参ります」

> 「（ク）は割愛いたします。次の（ケ）でございますが、……」

> 「（コ）は割愛いたしまして、（サ）に参ります」

A [敬語]{けいご} form of 「飛ばす」 is 「飛ばさせていただきます」.  Here is an example of the usage.

> 「おめくりいただきまして、[次]{つぎ}の７ページからは（シ）となっておりますが、９ページまで[飛]{と}ばさせていただきまして、（ス）に[参]{まい}りたいと[思]{おも}います」

Each of （イ）〜（ス） above represents the sectional title or a brief account/summary of the part which will be omitted. Because the speaker thinks that the part is still important although s/he omits it this time, s/he does not forget to present what the omitted part is about, especially when using 「割愛」.

However, there are many Japanese people who don't know the original meaning of「割愛する」 and think that the meaning of the word is "omit an unnecessary part". According to 『[平成23年度「国語に関する世論調査」の結果について](http://www.bunka.go.jp/tokei_hakusho_shuppan/tokeichosa/kokugo_yoronchosa/pdf/h23_chosa_kekka.pdf)』 published in [文化庁 official website](http://www.bunka.go.jp/tokei_hakusho_shuppan/tokeichosa/kokugo_yoronchosa/), the percentage of Japanese people who understood the original meaning was 17.6% and 65.1% Japanese people believed the "unnecessary"-version meaning.

Anyway, although people understand the meaning of the word differently, the ways to use the word 「割愛」 are almost same in most cases. It's still a formal word, and people use 「割愛」 in a formal situation. If the speaker uses the word 「割愛」, the listeners would think that the speaker is trying to omit it politely.

Answer (score 3):

時間の関係で1節飛ばします might be a plain expression, but...

What occasion have you got in mind? Your dissertation defense, say? In that case more polite expressions will be preferable.

***   added   ***
You will read your paper at a conference? Then

> 時{じ}間{かん}の関{かん}係{けい}で、次{じ}節{せつ}は割{かつ}愛{あい}させて戴{いただ}き、第{だい}x節{せつ}に移{うつ}ります　(where "x" is the section where you are to jump to.)

would be much better.

Comment: I will read my 論文 at a 学会 tomorrow. I only have 25 minutes to read it aloud. Since the paper would require 50 minutes to read the entire thing out loud, I need to skip some parts. It is a formal setting at a university. The main hope is that the 学会 members will decide to publish the paper as an academic journal article (fulfilling my requirement to graduate), so I want to give them the best impression possible.

Comment: By the way, do you hand over the abstract in advance? That may make your speech more acceptable to the audience.

Comment: I will hand out a printed copy of the entire paper to each person, so yes, they will be looking at the text while I read.

Comment: If the sections are ordered （ア）、（イ）、（ウ）、etc. should it be: 「時間の関係で、次節は割愛させて頂だき、（イ）に移ります。」?

Comment: After doing it the first time, do I omit the 「時間の関係で、」and instead only say 「次節は割愛させて頂だき、（エ）に移ります。」?  For skipping a single long quotation, do I say:「次の引用は割愛させて頂だき、内村の引用に移ります。」?

Comment: 「次の引用は割愛させていただきまして、内村の引用に[参]{まい}ります」 sounds  nicer, I think. Mentioning 「時間の関係で」 just once would be a good idea. Here are variations of 割愛 and 飛ばさせていただきます. 「[続]{つづ}きまして[○○についての(詳細／資料／etc)]がございますが、[本日]{ほんじつ}は時間の関係[上]{じょう}、割愛させていただきます。次の２ページに参りまして（イ）からとなりますが、・・(reading)」、「続きまして、３ページ目に移りまして（ウ）がございますが、こちらは割愛させていただきまして、（エ）に参ります」、「次の[○○についての(詳細／資料／etc)]は割愛させていただきまして、５ページ[目]{め}の（オ）に参ります」、「おめくりいただきまして、次の７ページからは[○○についての(詳細／資料／etc)]となっておりますが、９ページまで飛ばさせていただきまして、（カ）に参りたいと思います」

Comment: @HiruneDiver コメントだと読みにくいので回答欄にまとめていただいた方が読みやすいかと・・・

Comment: @chocoさん、アドバイスありがとうございます。eltonjohnさんの回答の応用の範囲だと思いましたのでコメントにしてみましたが、確かに読みにくいですね。回答にするほうが、サイト利用に不慣れなユーザにも親切かもしれないと思い直しまして、コメントの内容＋αを回答にまとめました。